# How do I expand a row into multiple rows with the same data in each row based on the number of the current cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Row 1-4 is the example of the data I'm given and I'm trying to achieve rows 7-17. The real list I'm working with is over 10,000 lines long, so if I can use the same formula on the entire list that would be perfect Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm an amateur at excel.

[image: Better Quality Image attached here]

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to achieve this through formulas.

You will need to code a Visual Basic program to do it. If you want to try that, use the Macro Recorder and manually duplicate the first line out, changing the numbers, and then look at the recorded Macro. It is not a simple task, and even an experienced coder might need half an hour or more for it.

Here is my recommendation for a *manual* approach (assuming you need this only done *once*, not over and over):

1. find the max value of copies you'll need, for example 20.
2. copy all lines 20 times below the existing block
3. fill all fields in the copied lines with a formula that takes the value above it and adds 1
4. sort the whole bunch. Now you should have each original 20 times, with the number counting upwards. Those four steps should take less than a minute.
5. delete the superfluous rows, block by block (that is the tedious part)